# C# linq / Lambda - Adding an item to a list that summarizes all the items in the list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have al list of `Purches` items

I want to add new item to my list, that sum all the items in my list

this is my code:

```
    public class Purches
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Items { get; set; }
        public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 List<Purches> purchesList = new List<Purches>() {
        new Purches() {
            Id = 1,
            Items = 3,
            TotalPrice = 220
        },
        new Purches() {
            Id = 2,
            Items = 5,
            TotalPrice = 300
        }
   };
```

now, I want to add the list new item that sum the `Items` and the `TotalPrice` properties

the result will be something like that:

```
 List<Purches> purchesList = new List<Purches>() {
                new Purches() {
                    Id = 1,
                    Items = 3,
                    TotalPrice = 220
                },
                new Purches()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Items = 5,
                    TotalPrice = 300
                },
                new Purches()
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Items = 8,
                    TotalPrice = 550
                }
            };
```

I have to do it via linq / Lambda in c#

Comment: Can you give a little more context around this requirement? Is it for a receipt for example?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend adding a summary item of the same type. That is just likely to lead to confusion. A better solution would be to to use either a separate object for the total, or use different types with a shared interface, for example:

```
public class PurchaceSummary{
    public List<Purches> Purchases {get;}
    public TotalItemCount => Items.Sum(p => p.Items);
    public TotalPrice => Items.Sum(p => p.TotalPrices);
}
```

Or

```
public interface IPurchaseLineItem{
    public int Items { get;  }
    public int TotalPrice { get;  }
}
public interface Purchase : IPurchaseLineItem{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Items { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
public interface PurchaseSummary : IPurchaseLineItem{
    public int Items { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
// Use the LINQ methods from the previous example to create your totals for the summary
```

In either case it should be immediately obvious for everyone what each value represents.

Comment: Sure, the requirement is little bit weird, but it's stated also in the title that OP needs to add it to the list. At least the summary item can be identified easily with the `Id=0`. But i agree, better would be to not put them all into the same list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm assuming the OP is fairly inexperienced, intends to do something like a receipt, and that adding another object of the same type was the first idea that came to mind. I think it is fair to point better alternative solutions in such cases. And I *really* dislike often undocumented rules like 'summary if Id == 0'.

Comment: You're right. But in future people will come here to find the receipt for adding a summary item to their list, and then they want an answer for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Purches totalSum = new Purches
{
    Id = 0,
    Items = purchesList.Sum(p => p.Items),
    TotalPrices = purchesList.Sum(p => p.TotalPrices)
};
// now add it to your list if desired
```